# If ordinary electron microscopes have wavelengths 5,000 times or more shorter than visible light, why can't they see atoms?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, atoms, wavelength, microscopy

Electron microscopes can easily 'see' down to .1 nanometers (1 ångstrom) or less, correct?  And a single hydrogen atom, in its ground state, is about .106 nanometers (Bohr diameter) wide, right?

So why are Scanning-tunneling microscopes needed to see individual atoms?

Comment: As I understand it, diffraction is fundament limit of any [optical system](https://www.ou.edu/research/electron/bmz5364/resolutn.html). Also there's aberrations, etc.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't. Individual atom locations can be seen in transmission electron microscopy and field-ion microscopy.